# Good REST design with Jackson/Gson

Tags: java, json, rest, backbone.js, jackson

I've been developing using Jackson for a couple of years now, but there was always something bothering me:

My models on the server has relations to one another. An example would be the following:
A `Lock` has a `Person` which has a list of `LogEntry` and each `LogEntry` has a `Lock`.
To get a lock i call `/api/lock/id` and i would retrieve the persons and log entries as well, however `LogEntry` references `Lock` so it would become an infinite loop.

Is there a good way/standard to follow when designing your models? Maybe one should only return the ID's of the references?

I want to avoid circular references(which is impossible with annotations in many cases) but i would also like to avoid writing serializers.

Do you have any other suggestions? (FYI: Im most often using **Backbone** on the client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. One is to only return links to the related item rather than embedding the entire resource. If you need to, you can support a query parameter `?expand=` which tells the server to embed the entire resource. The other option is to create a separate resource to manage the relationship, such as /log-entry-locks, which might look something like

```
GET /log-entry-locks?log-entry=15
[{
    "id": 1345,
    "log-entry": "/log-entries/15",
    "lock": "/locks/22"
},
{
    "id": 1346,
    "log-entry": "/log-entries/15",
    "lock": "/locks/46"
}]
```

Comment: I like the second option you demonstrated. I think i'm going to try this for a while and see how it works out with Backbone. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have other solutions, for example JSON-LD, and any other RDF format can describe graphs. Or by multiple calls your client can remember the URLs of the already retrieved resources, so it won't call them again...

Comment: Just to mention, following hyperlinks by REST is not an option, your client should always use a hyperlink - built by the service - to send a request. (aka uniform interface / HATEOAS constraint)

Comment: @inf3rno could you elaborate and maybe show an example? I looked up JSON-LD but didn't fully understand what it was about.

Comment: It binds RDF vocabularies to the data the server sends to your client. So the client can understand what are the specific parts of the data for. I guess currently your client parses the JSON but have not idea about the semantics of the properties. So it uses property names to fetch the data instead of the semantics. By JSON-LD you can add semantics to the property names by defining a @context. So your client can use the semantics to find the right property instead of a property name which can always change. It's just the same by the links, you have to add semantics to them as well.

Comment: Currently most ppl use HAL+JSON, IANA link relations and vendor specific MIME types for this purpose. HAL+JSON is for describing the interface of REST APIs, link relation is for describing the meaning of links, and vendor specific MIME types are for describing the body of the messages. These are coarse grained solutions. RDF is a fine grained solution, but it is harder to understand and implement. You have to read more about this topic to fully understand... [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), [Hydra REST vocab](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/)